# Need help correcting Homework code, C++ input/output

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm in my first intro to Comp Sci course. The assignment I have is inputting a `.txt` file and then outputting a revised `.txt` file. The first problems I had was just with fixing the directories. I did and everything came out fine with the `.txt` files, except the professor says I have an error in the `switch` statement.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int s = -2, a = 0, b = 0, NumIn;

    ifstream inFile("NumbersIn.txt");
    if (inFile.fail()) {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    ofstream outFile("RevisedNumbers.txt");
    while (!inFile.eof()) {
        inFile >> NumIn;
        cout << NumIn << endl;
        if (NumIn < 0)
            NumIn = -1;
        else if (NumIn > 0)
            NumIn = 1;
        outFile << NumIn << endl;
        switch (NumIn) {
        case -1:
            a += s;
            break;
        case 0:
            s += 1;
        case 1:
            b += s;
        }
    }
    outFile.close();
    inFile.close();
    cout << "A = " << a << endl;
    cout << "B = " << b << endl;
    cout << "S = " << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 0
 -2
 9
 14
 -22
 12
 6
 -9
 12
 13
 -33
 21
 9
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 1
 A = -4
 B = -9
 S = 0
 Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I'm including the assignment question here, so the reason why I used `s`, `a`, and `b` as integers:

> You program will require the following files
> Input file:  NumbersIn.txt  (attached to this assignment)
> Output file: RevisedNumbers.txt
> You program will use the following variables:
> int  s=-2, a = 0, b = 0. NumIn;
> As long as there is data in the input file, your program will read a number into the variable NumIn, print it on the screen,  and then determine the following:
> If NumIn is negative change it to -1
> If NumIn is positive change it to +1
> If NumIn is zero, do nothing
> Write the new value of NumIn to the output file RevisedNumbers
> After updating NumIN, use a switch statement to based on the current value of NumIn
> When NumIn is -1 increase the value of A by S
> When NumIn is 0 increment S by 1
> When NumIn is 1 increase the value of B by S
> When you no longer have data to read in print out the current value of A, B and S.
>
> Submit a copy of your program.
> The screen output
> The input file.
> The output file.

Comment: You use a `break` after the first `case` of your `switch` statement, but not for the rest of the cases. Why is that?

Comment: What is the program supposed to do? case 0: and case 1: don't have breaks, so case 0 will fall through to case 1, is this intentional?

Comment: There is also [a serious problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) with your input loop.

Comment: It would be easier to guess what your program is supposed to do - and thus tell what's wrong - if you didn't use nonsense names like "s", "a", and "b", and gave a more specific description of the process than "revised".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version:

```
    switch (NumIn) {
    case -1:
        a += s;
        break;
    case 0:
        s += 1;
    case 1:
        b += s;
    }
```

To fix it, add two break statements:

```
    switch (NumIn) {
    case -1:
        a += s;
        break;
    case 0:
        s += 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        b += s;
        break;
    }
```

Without them, case 0 falls through to case 1. It's actually legal to do that, but considered a common bug, so you should ALWAYS make a comment if your fall-through is intentional. I presume this time it isn't.

Comment: "*It's actually legal to do that, but considered a common bug*" - which is why most compilers have warnings for it. "*you should ALWAYS make a comment if your fall-through is intentional*" - in fact, C++17 adds a [`[[fallthrough]]` attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough) for that exact purpose.